# Set Mock Response for JWT Module NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jestjs, jwt

I am writing Test case using JEST in NodeJs inside AzureFunction.
Im trying to mock JWT module outcome inside my index.test.js , however its not working and getting timedout. I wonder is it the return datatype mismatch? How to set response similar to cb of jwt verify method?

Here is my sample code. Please suggest!

Index.js

```
const JWT = require('./jwtDecoder')
module.exports = function(context, req) {
try {
    JWT(req.body, process.env.jwtsecret, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            context.log("Invalid JWT::" + req.body);
            context.res = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                status: 400,
                body: {
                    "error": err

                }
            };
            context.done();
        } else {
            context.log("JWT Authentication Successful:");
            context.res = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                status: 200,
                body: {
                    "message": "success"
                }
            };
            context.done();

        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    context.log("Exception in main function, PushHttpFunction:" + err);
    context.res = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        status: 500,
        body: {
            "error": err
        }
    };
    context.done();
}
}
```

jwtDecoder.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (body, secret, cb) => {
console.log('inside jwtDecoder');
if (!body) {
    return cb(new Error('invalid jwt data'));
}

require('jsonwebtoken').verify(body.toString('utf8'), secret, { algorithm: 'HS256' }, cb);
};
```

index.test.js

```
let indexTest = require('../index')
const { runStubFunctionFromBindings } = require('stub-azure-function-context')

let JWT = require('../jwtDecoder')
jest.mock("../jwtDecoder.js")

/* verify.mockImplementation(() => () => ({
    err: new Error('invalid jwt data'),
    decoded: 'ok'
})); */
JWT.mockImplementation(() => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('ok');
}));

beforeAll(() => {
    process.env = Object.assign(process.env, {
        NODE_ENV: "test",
    });
});

describe('Simple Testing', () => {
    test('return 200 by mocking simpleFunc response" ', async() => {
        let request = {
            body: "dummy.jwt.zT5p"
        };
    const context = await runStubFunctionFromBindings(indexTest, [
        { type: 'httpTrigger', name: 'req', direction: 'in', data: request },
        { type: 'http', name: 'res', direction: 'out' },
    ], new Date());
    console.log('mockedResp::', context);

    expect(context.res.status).toEqual(200);
}, 30000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are mocking wrong, you can keep only this line:

```
jest.mock('./jwtDecoder.js', () => (res, req, cb) => cb(null, 'ok'))
```

as you need to mock callback

and remove all this part:

```
jest.mock("../jwtDecoder.js")
JWT.mockImplementation(() => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('ok');
}));
```